# How do you manually input the rotation point in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape 1.0beta1 (32d4812, 2019-09-19) for macOS, the center of rotation can only (afaik) be set by dragging the crosshair.

I'd like to know how to manually input a specific location (coordinates) for the center of rotation to ensure that rotated objects end up in their intended location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bit of testing and research, I found a [reference](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/inkscape/+spec/rotation-center-position) that may be of value.

The suggestion is:

> That's something you can already do thanks to the XML editor. The
>   rotation center attributes are inkscape:transform-center-x and
>   inkscape:transform-center-y.

It's relatively easy to make this work. I tried it out without complication.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about those parameters. Still a pain if you're rotating multiple objects at once that aren't a group, but at least they can be precisely set.

Comment: @AndrewFan You could always [request it as a feature](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/), perhaps as an option in the Tranform panel.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do, snapping the rotation center to a guide's origin:

[image: rotate around specific coordinate in Inkscape]

Comment: (no idea why that gif plays so slowly, sorry)

Comment: Seems like using guides is a viable workaround, even if it adds more steps. The more you know.

Comment: There's a button to enable snapping to grids BTW: https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/can-a-pivotingtransfrom-crosshair-be-moved-and-made-to-snap-to-a-node-or-a-grid-point/